# Speed up loading of multiple CSV files

Tags: python, performance, csv, asynchronous

I am trying to write a parser/API for the France's public drug database (https://base-donnees-publique.medicaments.gouv.fr/). It consists of eight CSV files (in fact TSV as they use tabs), each from a few kB to 4MB, the biggest having ~20000 lines (each line representing a drug with its name, codes, prices, etc).

As these files may chance periodically, I'd like to parse them directly instead of creating a cleaner database (as I would probably have to recreate it regularly anyway).

Importing these files took a little time (about one second), so I tried to speed it up a bit and did some benchmarking of several methods, and I was surprised to see that the most basic one seemed to also be the fastest.

Here is my test code (sorry it is quite long). Each file is associated with a dedicated class to parse its lines. Basically, these classes are namedtuples with a custom classmethod to parse dates, numbers, etc.

```py
import pathlib
import enum
import datetime
from decimal import Decimal
from collections import namedtuple
import csv


def parse_date(date: str) -> datetime.datetime:
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y").date()


def parse_date_bis(date: str) -> datetime.datetime:
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y%m%d").date()


def parse_text(text):
    if not text:
        return ""
    return text.replace("<br>", "\n").strip()


def parse_list(raw):
    return raw.split(";")


def parse_price(price: str) -> Decimal:
    if not price:
        return None
    # Handles cases like "4,417,08".
    price = '.'.join(price.rsplit(",", 1)).replace(',', '')
    return Decimal(price)


def parse_percentage(raw: str) -> int:
    if not raw:
        return None
    return int(raw.replace("%", "").strip())


class StatutAdministratifPresentation(enum.Enum):
    ACTIVE = "Présentation active"
    ABROGEE = "Présentation abrogée"


class EtatCommercialisation(enum.Enum):
    DC = "Déclaration de commercialisation"
    S = "Déclaration de suspension de commercialisation"
    DAC = "Déclaration d'arrêt de commercialisation"
    AC = "Arrêt de commercialisation (le médicament n'a plus d'autorisation)"


class MotifAvisSMR(enum.Enum):
    INSCRIPTION = "Inscription (CT)"
    RENOUVELLEMENT = "Renouvellement d'inscription (CT)"
    EXT = "Extension d'indication"
    EXTNS = "Extension d'indication non sollicitée"
    REEV_SMR = "Réévaluation SMR"
    REEV_ASMR = "Réévaluation ASMR"
    REEV_SMR_ASMR = "Réévaluation SMR et ASMR"
    REEV_ETUDE = "Réévaluation suite à résultats étude post-inscript"
    REEV_SAISINE = "Réévaluation suite saisine Ministères (CT)"
    NOUV_EXAM = "Nouvel examen suite au dépôt de nouvelles données"
    MODIF_COND = "Modification des conditions d'inscription (CT)"
    AUTRE = "Autre demande"


class ImportanceSMR(enum.Enum):
    IMPORTANT = "Important"
    MODERE = "Modéré"
    FAIBLE = "Faible"
    INSUFFISANT = "Insuffisant"
    COMMENTAIRES = "Commentaires"
    NP = "Non précisé"


class ImportanceASMR(enum.Enum):
    COM = "Commentaires sans chiffrage de l'ASMR"
    I = "I"
    II = "II"
    III = "III"
    IV = "IV"
    V = "V"
    NP = "Non précisée"
    SO = "Sans objet"


class Specialite(namedtuple("Specialite", ("cis", "denomation", "forme", "voies_administration", "statut_amm", "type_amm", "commercialisation", "date_amm", "statut_bdm", "numero_autorisation_europeenne", "titulaire", "surveillance_renforcee"))):
    @classmethod
    def from_line(cls, line):
        line[2] = line[2].replace("  ", " ").strip()
        line[3] = parse_list(line[3])
        line[7] = parse_date(line[7])
        line[10] = line[10].strip()  # There are often leading spaces here (like ' OPELLA HEALTHCARE FRANCE').
        return cls(*line)


class Presentation(namedtuple("Specialite", ("cis", "cip7", "libelle", "statut", "commercialisation", "date_commercialisation", "cip13", "agrement_collectivites", "taux_remboursement", "prix", "prix_hors_honoraires", "montant_honoraires", "indications_remboursement"))):
    @classmethod
    def from_line(cls, line):
        if line[3] == "Présentation active":
            line[3] = StatutAdministratifPresentation.ACTIVE
        else:
            line[3] = StatutAdministratifPresentation.ABROGEE
        line[4] = {
            "Déclaration de commercialisation": EtatCommercialisation.DC,
            "Déclaration de suspension de commercialisation": EtatCommercialisation.S,
            "Déclaration d'arrêt de commercialisation": EtatCommercialisation.DAC,
            "Arrêt de commercialisation (le médicament n'a plus d'autorisation)": EtatCommercialisation.AC
        }.get(line[4])
        line[5] = parse_date(line[5])
        line[7] = True if line[7] == "oui" else False
        line[8] = parse_percentage(line[8])
        line[9] = parse_price(line[9])
        line[10] = parse_price(line[10])
        line[11] = parse_price(line[11])
        line[12] = parse_text(line[12])
        return cls(*line)


class Composition(namedtuple("Composition", ("cis", "element", "code", "substance", "dosage", "ref_dosage", "nature_composant", "cle"))):
    @classmethod
    def from_line(cls, line):
        line.pop(-1)
        return cls(*line)


class AvisSMR(namedtuple("AvisSMR", ("cis", "dossier_has", "motif", "date", "valeur", "libelle"))):
    @classmethod
    def from_line(cls, line):
        line[2] = MotifAvisSMR(line[2])
        line[3] = parse_date_bis(line[3])
        line[4] = ImportanceSMR(line[4])
        line[5] = parse_text(line[5])
        return cls(*line)


class AvisASMR(namedtuple("AvisASMR", ("cis", "dossier_has", "motif", "date", "valeur", "libelle"))):
    @classmethod
    def from_line(cls, line):
        line[2] = MotifAvisSMR(line[2])
        line[3] = parse_date_bis(line[3])
        line[4] = ImportanceASMR(line[4])
        line[5] = parse_text(line[5])
        return cls(*line)


class AvisCT(namedtuple("AvisCT", ("dossier_has", "lien"))):
    @classmethod
    def from_line(cls, line):
        return cls(*line)


FILE_MATCHES = {
    "CIS_bdpm.txt": Specialite,
    "CIS_CIP_bdpm.txt": Presentation,
    "CIS_COMPO_bdpm.txt": Composition,
    "CIS_HAS_ASMR_bdpm.txt": AvisASMR,
    "CIS_HAS_SMR_bdpm.txt": AvisSMR,
    "HAS_LiensPageCT_bdpm.txt": AvisCT
}


def sequential_import_file_data(filename, cls):
    result = {cls: []}
    with (pathlib.Path("data") / filename).open("r", encoding="latin1") as f:
        rows = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
        for line in rows:
            data = cls.from_line(line)
            result[cls].append(data)
    return result


def import_data_sequential():
    results = []
    for filename, cls in FILE_MATCHES.items():
        results.append(sequential_import_file_data(filename, cls))


from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def import_data_mp_tp(n=2):
    pool = ThreadPool(n)
    results = []
    for filename, cls in FILE_MATCHES.items():
        results.append(pool.apply_async(
            sequential_import_file_data,
            (filename, cls)
        ))
    results = [r.get() for r in results]


from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

def import_data_mp_p(n=2):
    pool = Pool(n)
    results = []
    for filename, cls in FILE_MATCHES.items():
        results.append(pool.apply_async(
            sequential_import_file_data,
            (filename, cls)
        ))
    results = [r.get() for r in results]


import asyncio
import aiofiles
from aiocsv import AsyncReader

async def async_import_file_data(filename, cls):
    results = {cls: []}
    async with aiofiles.open(
        (pathlib.Path("data") / filename),
        mode="r",
        encoding="latin1"
    ) as afp:
        async for line in AsyncReader(afp, delimiter="\t"):
            data = cls.from_line(line)
            results[cls].append(data)
    return results


def import_data_async():
    results = []
    for filename, cls in FILE_MATCHES.items():
        results.append(asyncio.run(async_import_file_data(filename, cls)))


def main():
    import timeit
    print(
        "Sequential:",
        timeit.timeit(lambda: import_data_sequential(), number=10)
    )
    print(
        "Multi ThreadPool:",
        timeit.timeit(lambda: import_data_mp_tp(), number=10)
    )
    print(
        "Multi Pool:",
        timeit.timeit(lambda: import_data_mp_p(), number=10)
    )
    print(
        "Async:",
        timeit.timeit(lambda: import_data_async(), number=10)
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So when I run it, I get the following result.

```
Sequential: 9.821639589001279
Multi ThreadPool: 10.137484730999859
Multi Pool: 12.531487682997977
Async: 30.953154197999538
```

The most basic solution of iterating through all files and through all their lines seems to also be the fastest.

So, did I do anything wrong which would slow the import? Or is it normal/expected to have such time differences?

**Edit 2023-08-15:** I realized that since all the files I need to parse are TSV (and they don't contain tabs in their values), I could still speed up the parsing by using a simple `line.strip('\n').split('\t')` instead of the CSV module, which saves another 40% in runtime. :) I'll probably post a Gist when I have a complete API for this database.

Comment: In the case of multiprocessing, the result of loading the file has to be serialized and sent back to the parent process to end up in the `results` array, this is probably why they are slower than expected. You may get a speed up over single-threaded if you could do all the work in the task function and not pass anything back to the parent.

Comment: The size of the disparity for the async solution is slightly surprising but the results really don't surprise me. The more complicated solutions add overhead to setup new processes or threads and communicate the results. And as much as I love Python I would use Go for a problem like this. It will be considerably faster and has better tools for analyzing the performance.

Comment: The files seems available rather [here](https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/base-de-donnees-publique-des-medicaments-defi-idoc-sante/) instead. Besides, it is not clea what `cls` is supposed to be or variables like `Specialite`, `Presentation`, etc. On my machine, loading the CSV in sequential without the `cls` part takes ~36 ms/file, so ~300 ms for the whole process. It looks like your computation takes 1000 ms on your machine. Thus, unless you have a much slower processor, I guess the slow part is in `cls`. A more reproducible would help us.

Comment: Assuming the slow part is the CSV loading, then the most computing part is certainly the parsing. The bad news is that in Python, parallel computing is not efficient, especially here. Multithreading will not be efficient because of the GIL. The GIL cannot be avoided/disabled here since the CSV mostly contain strings objets (of variable size). Thus, multithreading will be useless. Multiprocessing is not efficient either since all strings needs to be pickled+unpickled and sent to the master process which is very expensive. There is no other standard way to do parallel computation with CPython.

Comment: I think the only efficient solution is to compute this in a native module (e.g. C/C++) and return exactly the computed object you want. Note that if the final objets contain many CPython strings objets, then this will not be much better because of the GIL. In this case, the only possible workaround is to use a native data structure with native string wrapped in an opaque CPython class. This is not convenient to use but at least more efficient. Put it shortly, CPython is pain for (fast) parallel computation like this.

Comment: How fast do you think this could (or should) be? Opening 9 files and processing 100K rows in **1 second** (with Python!) seems pretty quick to me. How often do you run this program that the latency feels burdensome?

Comment: In fact I downloaded the files from [here](https://base-donnees-publique.medicaments.gouv.fr/telechargement.php). I just updated the post to put the whole code. Sorry, it is quite long and probably a bit ugly. Also the source database is quite gross, with multiple date formats, percentages as strings, etc. As the import code only uses native Python functions, I thought they would be optimized enough not to be the bottleneck (compared to reading files from disk)...

Comment: And ideally I wanted to use this code as a module for others programs. So yeah, it is not critical to load these files in less than a second, in fact I was mostly surprised to see that my various attempts at parallelization only slowed down the import, and I was just wondering why (or how to avoid this)...

Comment: When you use `multiprocessing`, you end up paying quite the heavy price pickling and unpickling the data as it moves from one process to another – `multiprocessing` is honestly better suited to situations where each process can read and write their own data. `async` doesn't help you here either since it'll probably spend a whole lot of time context switching to see if there's other async work to be done (and of course there is). But as per usual: Did you run a profiler on your regular sequential code to see what the hotspots are?

Comment: Oh I see, I think I understand. Thanks for the explanation! I haven't done Python in a while, so I guess I've lost the good habits... ^^ I haven't tried a Profiler yet, but I'm going to and I'll let you know the results. :)

Comment: @MichaelMarx No need, I did it for you. ;-) See my answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual: run a profiler on your code to see where it's spending its time. (This is PyCharm's, it wraps the stdlib `cProfile`.)

> Sequential: 7.865187874995172

[image]

Huh, okay. `strptime`, I can tell that'd get called by `datetime.datetime.strptime`. Also, weird, `getlocale`... why do we need locales there? Clicking through to the call graph shows that `strptime` actually looks up the current locale, and has a bunch of locks and all that – what if we replace those `parse_date`s with our own implementations?

```
def parse_date(date: str) -> datetime.date:
    d, m, y = (int(x) for x in date.split("/", 2))
    return datetime.date(2000 + y, m, d)


def parse_date_bis(date: str) -> datetime.datetime:
    y = int(date[:4])
    m = int(date[4:6])
    d = int(date[6:8])
    return datetime.datetime(y, m, d)
```

> Sequential: 3.8978060420195106

Okay, we're cooking! 52% improvement right there!

[image]

(It doesn't show up on the screenshot here because I was a silly goose cropping it, but the `re` stuff that `strptime` uses under the hood dropped right off too.)

Now let's work with the assumption that there'll be a lot of the same date and slap `@lru_cache(maxsize=None)`s (RAM flex there, unbounded caches) on those hot `parse_date_*` functions, run the code and also print out the cache info:

```
Sequential: 3.2240814580000006
CacheInfo(hits=358989, misses=6991, maxsize=None, currsize=6991)
CacheInfo(hits=221607, misses=513, maxsize=None, currsize=513)
```

Looks pretty good to me, we got another 15% off the last number.

`parse_price` could apparently use a cache too, though:

[image]

```
Sequential: 2.928746833000332
CacheInfo(hits=358989, misses=6991, maxsize=None, currsize=6991)
CacheInfo(hits=221607, misses=513, maxsize=None, currsize=513)
CacheInfo(hits=622064, misses=4096, maxsize=None, currsize=4096)
```

Hey, who knew, there was only 4096 individual price strings in the data.

The remaining parsing functions could use a cache too if you have the memory, but with a little bit of profiling and parsing elbow grease, it's now 2.7x faster [when running everything 10 times, which means those caches will be hot – a single run's speedup isn't as dramatic], with no parallel processing required. Magic!

And just so the playing ground is a bit more even, here's a `hyperfine` benchmark where the Python interpreter is started from scratch for each import (and each interpreter runs the import only once):

```
$ hyperfine 'python3 so76781391-orig.py' 'python3 so76781391-opt.py' --warmup 5 --min-benchmarking-time 10
Benchmark 1: python3 so76781391-orig.py
  Time (mean ± σ):     363.0 ms ±   2.7 ms    [User: 340.8 ms, System: 20.7 ms]
  Range (min … max):   358.9 ms … 367.9 ms    27 runs

Benchmark 2: python3 so76781391-opt.py
  Time (mean ± σ):     234.1 ms ±   2.5 ms    [User: 215.6 ms, System: 17.0 ms]
  Range (min … max):   228.2 ms … 238.5 ms    42 runs

Summary
  'python3 so76781391-opt.py' ran
    1.55 ± 0.02 times faster than 'python3 so76781391-orig.py'
```

so, 55% concrete speed boost with a quick look at the profiler (and a couple of additional optimizations such as not creating mapping dicts within `from_line` functions, etc., etc.).

Comment: Good job. Improving the sequential time is certainly the best we can do with CPython. Note that Cython can improve the speed of function calls and remove some interpreter overheads. Note that `parse_price` can be improved further using Cython by calling `price.encode('ascii')` so to convert the string in a bytearray and then parsing the resulting value manually with a memory-view based loop. The use `Decimal` might be replaced by `float` here since `float` already give at least 15 digits (relative) and prices should not be bigger than 1000 billion euros (a bit too expensive even for countries)

Comment: @JérômeRichard I doubt a Python-based loop would be faster (Cython maybe!), but using `rpartition` instead of `rsplit` would definitely help (a tiny bit) – but seeing as slapping a cache on `parse_price` says `CacheInfo(hits=58520, misses=4096, maxsize=None, currsize=4096)` (with one invocation, not `timeit`) it's not worth the effort when it simplifies to just a dict lookup :)

Comment: Oh, and in fact, since the prices in the data are always 2-decimal, one could just `int(x.replace(",", "")) / 100` and be done with it, but the current approach is certainly more robust.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much! It's also very instructive on the logic and method of optimizing code. :)